# scroll snap is not stopping at top / bottom of page

Tags: css

https://jonathanrace77.github.io/index.html

Scroll-snap is working great... except when it gets to the top or bottom of the screen and you are able to keep scrolling past the content...

I can't figure out how to stop this from happening.

```
html {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A combo of

```
main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

&

```
.top {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  bottom: -10vh;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 10vh;
}
```

...was screwing things up. After randomly deleting sections of CSS, this managed to fix it.